# LSM9DS1 inactivity mode

Tags: accelerometer, gyro, magnetometer

The datasheet of the [LSM9DS1](https://www.digikey.com/htmldatasheets/production/1639232/0/0/1/LSM9DS1-Datasheet.pdf) says on page 41:

```
ACT_THS (04h) Activity threshold register
Gyroscope operating mode during inactivity. Default value: 0
- 0: gyroscope in power-down
- 1: gyroscope in sleep mode

ACT_DUR (05h) Inactivity duration register
```

I omitted some non-important details above. I do not see in the documentation an explanation of what should actually happen to make the gyro go to sleep or power down? Just modulo of angular speeds below the threshold for the specified duration, or something else? How about acceleration? Is it involved either or this inactivity is just about the Gyro?

There are other related questions:

Is it possible to disable this inactivity mode?
What should happen to make it active again?
Will any reading be lost or altered during the sleep and re-activation?